# sum columns in dataframe python (different columns each row)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `a, b, c` like below:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,5,3], 'b':[2,0,6,1], 'c':[4,3,1,4]})`

I want to add column `d` which is sum of some columns in `df`, but is not the same column for each row, for example

[image]

only row 1 and 3 is sum from the same column, row 0 and 2 is sum from others columns.

what I found on Stack over flow is always for certain column for whole dataframe, but in this case it is differnt.

How is the best way I can do it?

Comment: ` but is not the same column for each row` What is the logic behind the columns chosen for each row?

Comment: there is no logic behind...

Comment: You mean they are selected randomly?

Comment: Why the third row is equal to a?

Comment: no, it is randomly, it just no same rule for all rows

Comment: @DaniMesejo it is just a example, of cause my real dataframe is not the same

Comment: What are the rules? Otherwise how are people is going to create an approach for solving your issue?

Comment: sorry I have a mistake in the expected df, column d of row 1 and 3 have the same rule, is sum of column a and c

Comment: Is d=a+c the rule for every odd row?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos in this case yes, but I mean for some certain rows, in this example row 1 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because column `d` is randomly calculated, the only way to do it for each row, is separately.

```py
df['d'] = 0
df['d'].iloc[0] = df['b'].iloc[0]
df['d'].iloc[1] = df['a'].iloc[1] + df['c'].iloc[1]
df['d'].iloc[2] = df['a'].iloc[2]
df['d'].iloc[3] = df['a'].iloc[3] + df['c'].iloc[3]
```

If rows 1 and 3, have a rule:

```py
df['d'].loc[(df.index % 2)==1] = df['a'].iloc[df.index] + df['c'].iloc[df.index]
```

Also, with `for-loop`:

```py
for i in range(0, 4): 
    if i % 2 == 1: 
        df['d'].iloc[i] = df['a'].iloc[i] + df['c'].iloc[i]
```

Comment: sorry I have a mistake in the expected df, column d of row 1 and 3 have the same rule, is sum of column a and c, how can I do it for both rows at the same time?

Comment: please tell me if it works, so I can change it,if not. @actnmk

Comment: it works! thank you so much

Comment: L. Papadopoulos, this is a blatant duplicate of [Dynamically evaluate expression from formula in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamically-evaluate-expression-from-formula-in-pandas). People will generally vote to close as dupe, and you're not going to earn rep from an answer on a closed dupe.

Comment: @smci i just saw the answer. It is so big, that the guy asking, may get confused. It is better that I wrote what he just needs.

Comment: L. Papadopoulos, I didn't say you plagiarized this. I did say that the **question** was a blatant dupe, which I already flagged 30 min ago, and when the question is known to be a dupe, [the proper SO behavior is to vote to close as a dupe in favor of the target question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), not to answer it. Additionally, you could adapt this answer and post it there (answer would need to restate the example formula you're trying to solve, obviously).

Comment: ...yes that [that target answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779987/202229) is way too long and needs structure and concise specific examples, I'm separately editing it, you could also suggest improvements there via comments. But that's not an excuse to knowingly not close this as a dupe.

Comment: @smci thanks for your comment, I have read the answer and its too Long and for a beginner like me not easy to understand

Comment: @smci i agree that duplicates must close. But actnmk is beginer as he says, and my answer is beginer-friendly, because it is small, and on point, without confusing explanations. The other answer you say, does not need to get smaller, it is like a wiki answer, that analyses a problem and gives multiple solutions.

Comment: I posted a one-line solution that uses `pd.eval()` to dynamically evaluate a different `df['formula']` on each line, no manual hardcoding required. (Eventually that other long answer needs to be slimmed down and updated with this sort of thing)

Answer (score -2):

**The dynamic way uses `pd.eval()`**, as per [this solution][1]. This evaluates each row's formula individually, which **allows `df['formula']` to be different on each row, and nothing is hardcoded in your code**. There's a huge amount going on in this one-liner, see the explanation in Notes below.

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.eval(row['formula'], local_dict=row.to_dict()), axis=1)

0    2
1    4
2    5
3    4
#    ^--- this is the result
```

and if you want to assign that result to a dataframe column, say `df['z']`:

- `df['z'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.eval(row['formula'], local_dict=row.to_dict()), axis=1)`
- alternatively you could use `pd.eval(..., inplace=True)`, but then the formula would need to contain an actual assignment, e.g. 'z=a+b', and also the 'z' column would need to have been declared already: `df['z'] = np.NaN`. That part is slightly annoying to implement, so I didn't.

NOTES:

1. we use `pd.eval(...)` to dynamically evaluate the `['formula']` column

   - ...using the `pd.eval(.., local_dict=...)` argument to pass in the variables for that row
2. to evaluate an expression on each dataframe **row**, we use `df.apply(..., axis=1)`. We have to provide some lambda function to tell it what to evaluate.
3. So how does `pd.eval()` know how to map the strings `a`,`b`,`c` to their values on that individual row?

   - When we call `df.apply(..., axis=1)` row-wise like that, each row gets passed in as an individual Series, so within our `apply(... axis=1)`, we can no longer reference the dataframe as `df` or its columns as `df['a'], df['b'], ...`
   - So instead we need to pass in that row as a Python dict, hence the `local_dict=row.to_dict()` argument to `pd.eval`, inside the lambda function.
4. The `pd.eval()` approach can handle arbitrarily complicated formulas in the variables, not just simple sums; it can handle e.g. `(a + c**2)/(b+c)`. You could reference external constants, or external functions e.g. `log10`.

References:
[1]: [Compute dataframe columns from a string formula in variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305007/compute-dataframe-columns-from-a-string-formula-in-variables)